# How do handle dimensionality problems of derivatives of vectors?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I struggle with the following tasks.

To derive $h$ I would use the Quotient rule(?).

When I derive the numerator after $x$ so $$\frac{\partial (y-g(x))^2}{\partial x} = 2 \cdot (y-g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

a dimensionality problem occur. $2 \cdot (y-g(x))$ is a (nx1) vector while $g'(x)$ should be a $nx3 matrix (?). How should I handle this?

Same problem with the denominator:
$$\frac{\partial (1+(y-g(x))^2)}{\partial x} = 2 \cdot (y-g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

I would appreciate any advice

Edit: Here is my new complete solution:

Comment: Use the multivariable chain rule properly and carefully — with matrix product of derivatives. Your first vector should be transposed. What’s the derivative of $h(x)=\|x\|^2$?

Comment: Just to be sure. $h(x)$ seems to be the fraction of two vectors: should we understand it is taken elementwise ? Idem for the power of two. Finally when you add 1 to a vector (in the denominator) it is a vector of ones that we should consider ?

Comment: The derivative of $h(x)=\|x\|^2$ is $2x$. But why should it be transposed? I know the chain rule, but do not understand why especially the first vector should be transposed like: $2 \cdot (y-g(x))^T \cdot g'(x)$.

@Steph Well h(x) could be anything e.g. a function of functions $g(x)=(sin(x),cos(x),...)$
I do not know why there is a 1 in the denominator, but $(y-g(x))^2$ will be a 1x1 (vector) scalar in the end, so it doesn't matter.


Sry for the late answer.

Comment: $h$ doesn't seem to be well defined. What is $\frac{1}{1+(y-g(x))^2}$ if $y-g(x)\in\Bbb R^n$ and $n>1$? I echo what Steph is asking, your response doesn't make sense to me. Did you instead intend to write $(y-g(x))^T(y-g(x))$?

Comment: No, $(y-g(x))^2$ is correct. Its a task of an exam from 2 years ago. I Think they do not care if h is well defined. Its not a pure math module and they just want a derivative, even if the function is one some points problematic. Oh now I see what u mean (y-g(x))^T(y-g(x)) != (y-g(x))^2 mmh

Comment: The derivative is a linear map; the gradient is a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the notations of the exam (?) are very messy. If I understand correctly from your indications, $x^2$ means the squared norm (which is a poor notation).
Let denote
$
\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}
$.

The scalar-valued function $h$ writes
$$
h = \frac{\|\mathbf{u}\|^2}{1+\|\mathbf{u}\|^2}
$$
i.e.
$$
\|\mathbf{u}\|^2
=
\frac{1}{1-h}-1
$$
Taking the differential
$$
2 \mathbf{u}:d\mathbf{u}
=
\frac{dh}{(1-h)^2}
$$
where the colon operator : denotes the inner product between two vectors.

It follows
$$
dh
=2(1-h)^2 \mathbf{u}:d\mathbf{u}
=2(1-h)^2 \mathbf{u}:\mathbf{J}_g\ d\mathbf{x}
=\color{red}{2(1-h)^2 \mathbf{J}_g^T \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{x}
$$
The LHS term is the gradient of $h$ and $\mathbf{J}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ is the Jacobian of $\mathbf{g}$ wrt $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Isn't $h = \frac{\|\mathbf{u}\|^2}{1+\|\mathbf{u}\|^2}$, $\|\mathbf{u}\|^2
=
\frac{1}{1-h}-1$ a endless recursive call  ?

Comment: no just a trick to compute the differential of h, but I could have go directly from the definition of $h$

Comment: ok thx. then my edit solution is completely wrong:(

Comment: Why completely wrong? The $(1-h^2)$ term I got correspond to your denominator. So for me, it is quite identical : You simply have the transposed gradient of mine which is a matter of convention. I think my derivation is slightly better since it implies quantities you have already computed.